# using is operator in actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript, operators, instanceof

I am trying to use is operator to compare a variable against a user defined class but my compiler is giving it as an error.
my question is: can we use the 'is' operator to compare only to the in built types or can it be used for comparing with the user defined types as well.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used for user defined types too.

A correct syntax looks like:

```
var myVar1:MyClass;
var myVar2:OtherClass;
if ( myVar1 is MyClass ) trace("myClass"); // this trace executes.
if ( myVar1 is OtherClass ) trace("true"); // this trace does not execute (if OtherClass does not extend MyClass
```